# How to get ARGS from XppPrePostArgs in extension methos?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365

I extended the *main* class method, I would like to get from XppPrePostArgs the **Args** in D365 environment.

```
[PreHandlerFor(classStr(MYCLASS), staticMethodStr(MYCLASS, main))]
public static void MYCLASS_Pre_main(XppPrePostArgs args)
{
     // HOW TO CONVERT args to 
    //   from XppPrePostArgs  get Args
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not converting anything in the traditional [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-inheritance) sense. You're using [`XppPrePostArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.dynamics.ax.xpp.xppprepostargs) to obtain the event's variable(s).

`// Change "_args" to whatever the argument variable name is`

`Args args = _xppPrePostArgs.getArg("_args");`